# Why is the 20px right padding of my site being cut off on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, css

BAsically, this is what's happening:

Browser:

[image]

Iphone (it doesn't happen in Android):

[image]

I'm using this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = yes">
```

And this is the CSS:

```
html,
body,
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

body > #wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#content {
  clear: both;
  padding-bottom: 36px;
}

#header,
#content,
#footer {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}

#footer {
  background: url(images/footer_bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
  margin: -65px 0 0;
  padding: 15px 0 14px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  height: 36px;
}
```

Live sample:

http://www.pixelmatic.com/games/

I'm puzzled so far. What could be the cause?

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ No, it's pretty old. It means: only affect the immediate child element.

Answer (score 0):

I think the container width in .container style is an issue as it is in pixel instead of percentage.
Try using width in percentage.